# How to load run WPF and WCF application

Tags: wpf

Please tell any way to load run WPF application. Web service is implementd using WCF.

Comment: you it is the scenario you want to use this?

Answer (score 1):

WPF is a .EXE file run as any normal application in Windows.
WCF is (often) a web service that you access through HTTP protocol.

Could you be more specific on what your problem is / what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very wrong but i guess you have to create a client proxy or add a web reference for your WCF service in your WPF client to consume the service and start calling the service methods to get the job done!